# Cannot read Google Cloud Functions (gen2) logs via CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting the following error when trying to visualize logs of a cloud function I've deployed:

```
gcloud functions logs read MY_FUNCTION --region=MY_REGION --project=MY_PROJECT
WARNING: There is no function named `MY_FUNCTION` in region `MY_REGION`. Perhaps you meant to specify `--region` or update the `functions/region` configuration property?
Listed 0 items.
```

despite having a function with the given name, under the given region and project ids.

I cannot show much proof about it, but the GCF page's url is:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/details/MY_REGION/MY_FUNCTION?env=gen2&project=MY_PROJECT
```

and I'm 100% sure no typos are involved.

Comment: You have to look into the Cloud Run logs (....)

Comment: So logging from CLI is not possible for gen2 Cloud Functions and they don't even mention that?

Comment: It's still in preview, some features aren't available for now

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same problem, but after upgrading to the newest gcloud version, the logs finally are readable via CLI

```
gcloud --version

Google Cloud SDK 437.0.1
beta 2023.06.30
bq 2.0.93
core 2023.06.30
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.24
log-streaming 0.3.0
```

You can upgrade by

```
gcloud components update
```